# android studio project to save flash messages and notification

Tags: android, notifications, save

I have seen basic android studio tutorials and now I wish to develop app that will save flash messages and notifications. Somebody please tell me how to do so and provide useful links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html) link helped.

1. NotificationService.java

   package android.notifications;
   import android.app.Notification;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
   import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
   import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

   ```
   public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {  

   Context context;  

   @Override  

   public void onCreate() {  

       super.onCreate();  
       context = getApplicationContext();  

   }  
   @Override  

   public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {  
       String pack = sbn.getPackageName();  
       String ticker ="";  
       if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {  
           ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();  
       }  
       Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;  
       String title = extras.getString("android.title");  
       String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();  
       int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);  
       Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;  


       Log.i("Package",pack);  
       Log.i("Ticker",ticker);  
       Log.i("Title",title);  
       Log.i("Text",text);  

       Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");  
       msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);  
       msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);  
       msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);  
       msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);  
       if(id != null) {  
           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
           id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);  
           byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();  
           msgrcv.putExtra("icon",byteArray);  
       }  
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);  


   }  

   @Override  

   public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {  
       Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");  

   }
   ```

   }

2.MainActivity.java

```
package android.notifications;  

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.content.IntentFilter;  
import android.graphics.Bitmap;  
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.MenuItem;  
import android.widget.ListView;  

import java.util.ArrayList;  

/** 
 * Created by mukesh on 19/5/15. 
 */  
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

    ListView list;  
    CustomListAdapter adapter;  
    ArrayList<model> modelList;  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        modelList = new ArrayList<model>();  
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), modelList);  
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);  
        list.setAdapter(adapter);  
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("Msg"));  
    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu  
        return true;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
        switch (item.getItemId()) {  
            case R.id.action_settings:  
                Intent intent = new Intent(  
                        "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");  
                startActivity(intent);  
                return true;  
            default:  
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
        }  
    }  
    private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {  

        @Override  
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
           // String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");  
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");  
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");  
            //int id = intent.getIntExtra("icon",0);  

            Context remotePackageContext = null;  
            try {  
//                remotePackageContext = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(pack, 0);  
//                Drawable icon = remotePackageContext.getResources().getDrawable(id);  
//                if(icon !=null) {  
//                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setBackground(icon);  
//                }  
                byte[] byteArray =intent.getByteArrayExtra("icon");  
                Bitmap bmp = null;  
                if(byteArray !=null) {  
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);  
                }  
                Model model = new Model();  
                model.setName(title +" " +text);  
                model.setImage(bmp);  

                if(modelList !=null) {  
                    modelList.add(model);  
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
                }else {  
                    modelList = new ArrayList<model>();  
                    modelList.add(model);  
                    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), modelList);  
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);  
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);  
                }  

            } catch (Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
    };  
}
```

3. AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   package="android.notifications">  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>  
   <application  
       android:allowBackup="true"  
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
       android:label="@string/app_name"  
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">  
       <activity  
           android:name="android.notifications.MainActivity"  
           android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"  
           android:label="@string/app_name">  
           <intent-filter>  
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
           </intent-filter>  
       </activity>  
       <service  
           android:name="android.notifications.NotificationService"  
           android:label="@string/app_name"  
           android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SER                          VICE">  
           <intent-filter>  
               <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationLi                                  stenerService" />  
           </intent-filter>  
       </service>  
       <receiver android:name="android.notifications.IncomingSms">  
          <intent-filter>  
              <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />  
          </intent-filter>  
       </receiver>  
       <receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver" >  
           <intent-filter>  
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />  
           </intent-filter>  
       </receiver>  
   </application>
   ```